# How can I get my Microsoft LifeCam HD-3000 to work in Ubuntu 14.04.3

Tags: webcam

The image from my new Microsoft LifeCam HD-3000 will freeze right after I click "Record a Video" in Cheese and then appear to be recording normally. However, when I try to play the video in VLC it will just display a still image that lasts for about 1 second that loops continuously with no audio.